# XNA How to place objects with variable width and height in a map

Tags: xna, maps, game-engine, xna-4.0

I want to make a game where the player can place objects in an existing gamemap like a wall or different kind of turrets.

The gamemap consist 2 things:

- So basicaly the main gamemap where the player can walk around in, that exist of trees, walls and water that is already there.
- And the objects (with their specific heights and widths) that the player can place (when he gots wood, gold (when the player slays monsters etc) in that main gamemap.

How should I approach this? Any tips, class structures with methods would be nice to have.

Comment: You've just written how you should approach it. Now you have to figure out how you're going to do updates on all that. And it depends on what you want these things to do.

Comment: Im stuck at coding so any code would help

Comment: Look for Terraria-like game development guides. There are tons of tutorials out there to make a simple game that works like you describe, you just need to understand what exactly you can't figure out − map, updates, classes, maybe everything. Also check out [Cyral](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1218281/cyral)'s [Zarknorth](http://zarknorth.com/) game, it's something like Terraria, and you can ask him for some advice.

Answer (score 1):

The main gamemap could be a grid of tiles. Your turrets could then have width and height as multiples of the tile sizes and occupy a certain number of them.

For example, a 2x2 turret would occupy four tiles. Limiting turrets/walls to tiles rather than giving them arbitrary positions and lengths is limiting, but it allows you faster collision detection.

You could then have:

```cs
class Tile
{
   public Building WhatIsConstructedHereIfAnything;
}
```

and

```cs
class Building
{
   public List<Tile> TilesOccupiedByThisBuilding;
}
```

You could then update the building by going over the list of buildings and handle collisions only by looking at nearby tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Rectangle` to your object class, and use its `Width` and `Height` properties.

```cs
class YourObject
{
    public Rectangle Rectangle;

    public YourObject(Vector2 position, int width, int height)
    {
         Rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, width, height);
    }

    public void Draw() 
    {
        spritebatch.Draw(Texture, Rectangle, Color);
    }    
}
```